# Seg fault? Can you find it? cause I can't

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I've looked over this about 15 times by now to no avail. I cannot understand why this is seg faulting? It doesn't even get to the "print" statement which makes no sense. the error codes actually do work tho (when I dont have a shared memory present) I have a load.c program but it works perfectly (im 100% sure of this)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include "header.h"

//BEGIN MAIN FUNCTION
main()
{
    int id;             //ID to data shmem
    struct StudentInfo *infoptr;    //ptr to data
    int found = 0;          //found 'boolean'
    char input[15];         //user input buffer
    struct StudentInfo *beginptr;   //ptr to beginning of data
    int rcid;           //Read count ID to shmem
    int *rcptr;         //RC ptr
    int sema_set;           //ID to shared semaphores

    //Find the shmem at our ID
        id = shmget(KEY,SEGSIZE,0);
        if(id < 0)
        {
                perror("Query: shmget failed");
                exit(1);
        }

    //set the ptr to our shared mem and attach to program
        infoptr = (struct StudentInfo *)shmat(id,0,0);
        if(infoptr <= (struct StudentInfo *)(0))
        {
                perror("Query: shmat failed");
                exit(1);
        }

    //Get our RC in shared memory 
    rcid = shmget(RCKEY,READCOUNT,0);
    if(rcid < 0)
    {
        perror("Query: shmget failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    //Set ptr to shmem and attach to process
    rcptr = (int*)shmat(rcid,0,0);
    if(rcptr <= (int*)(0))
    {
        perror("Print: Shmat failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    //Get semaphores
    sema_set = semget(SEMA_KEY,NUM_SEMAPHS,0);
    if(sema_set < 0)
    {
        perror("Query: Semget failed");
        exit(1);
    }   

    //Set program to queue up to wait
    Wait(sema_set,1);

    //Increment the read counter
    *rcptr += 1;

    //If we are the first reader, stop writers
    if(*rcptr == 1)
    Wait(sema_set,0);

    //Signal readers
    Signal(sema_set,1);

    //Set our begin ptr
    beginptr = infoptr;

    //Begin user input loop
    while(1)
    {
    //Ask user for input IT DOESN"T EVEN GET TO HERE <--
    printf("Please input a student ID :");
    scanf("%s",input);

    //While the record is not found search  
    while(strcmp(infoptr->Name,"")!=0 && found != 1)
    {
        //If record found, print the record
        if((strncmp(input,infoptr->ID,9)) == 0)
        {
            //Set found
            found = 1;

            printf("\n%s\n",infoptr->Name);
                    printf("%s\n",infoptr->telNumber);
                    printf("%s\n",infoptr->Address);
                    printf("%s\n\n",infoptr->ID);
        }
        else
            infoptr++;
    }

    //If not found, print error message
    if(found == 0)
        printf("Record not found.\n");

    //Wait on readers
    Wait(sema_set,1);
    //Decrement
    *rcptr--;
    //If no readers left
    if(*rcptr == 0)
        Signal(sema_set,0); //Signal writers
    //Signal readers
    Signal(sema_set,1);
    exit(0);        
    }
}
```

HEADER

```
#define KEY  ((key_t)(11111)) /*change it to last five digits of your SSN*/
#define SEGSIZE  sizeof(struct StudentInfo)

#define NUM_SEMAPHS 2
#define SEMA_KEY   ((key_t)(1111)) /* change this to last four digits of SSN */

#define READCOUNT sizeof(int)   //Set the size of shmem for read count
#define RCKEY ((key_t)(4003))   //Set the key of the shmem for RCount

//Struct student info
struct StudentInfo{
  char Name[20];
  char ID[15];
  char Address[50];
  char telNumber[15];
};

//Checks the semaphore whether or not to wait
void Wait(int semaph, int n);
//Signals that it's ok to run
void Signal(int semaph, int n);
//Gets the semaphore information
int GetSemaphs(key_t k, int n);
```

Comment: 1. Have you tried valgrind? 2. The error might be inside of Wait or Signal or something else in header.h, we cannot know.

Comment: main() has to be declared returning an int

Comment: Start it in a debugger an see where the segfault occurs.  That will give you a hint.

Comment: If you expect us to find bugs in your code, at least attach it all so we don't struggle to compile it (ie. what is header.h?)

Comment: oops sorry ill attach header.h, however Im not familiar very much with using a debugger in unix (im used to Visual Studio, but since I use alot of Posix stuff I had to do it in unix). Any tips on using a debugger in unix? Also it's not the main int() thing I tried that and my other files dont have that either.

Comment: how are you compiling this? could you paste that here

Comment: In C, main() defaults to returning an int when no return type is specified for it - no worries there. What is the compiler you are using? Does the code "get to" the `beginptr` assignment before the `while(1)` ?

Comment: im using gcc in a big makefile. I've tried putting print statements before the while and such, but it seg faults regardless unless I put it at the LITERAL very beginning before I even declare stuff... Im doing gcc -o query query.c header.h

Comment: Comparing pointers to `NULL` with `<=` is at the very least bad style. I'm not even sure if it results in well-defined behavior in C.

Comment: Well i tried using g++ to compile, and it doesn't seg fault but it always fails on the first  id = shmget(KEY,SEGSIZE,0);
which is weird because I have the exact same statement in another file (literally exact same....) and it does it fine...

Comment: OK WHAT THE #*(&%%(#*, I just deleted everything, and changed my makefile to G++ for all the files and now it works perfectly.........

Comment: I believe you have the same problem here as in the rest of your flurry of questions about this same code...  Your string are likely not nul terminated.

Comment: Ya but all I did was change the compiler to g++.....whats that have to do with null termination? Does the G++ compiler fix that or something?

Comment: g++ probably compiles your code as C++ and not C. These are two different languages.

Comment: Ya i know...but, well I mean I guess it doesn't matter because it works perfectly now, but it does seem kinda weird.

Comment: `infoptr <= (struct StudentInfo *)(0)` I don't think <= is well defined in this context. If I recall correctly you may only use > and < on pointers that point to the same data-structure. And a pointer which has the sign bit set isn't necessarily invalid. For example if you enable the /3GB switch on windows you get such pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem might come from your use of `shmat`. In C, never cast the return type of such a function. That you felt the need for it probably means that you had a spurious error message that came from the fact that you are missing the "sys/shm.h" header.

What happens in such cases is that gcc takes the return type for an `int`, usually a 32 bit quantity, and re-interprets it as a pointer. So the upper half of your address that `shmat` gives you is lost.

As a general rule, don't cast away problems. Cast are rarely needed in C if all your headers are properly written. Casting the return type of a system function is almost always wrong.

Comment: Our professor had given us sample code so thats how he had it? I wouldn't of known better. It seems to be working well with G++ however tho. But I mean im new to shared memory so most of the classes code is adopted from his sample code <_<. I assuming ur referring to infoptr = (struct StudentInfo *)shmat(id,0,0);
 right?

Comment: Yes, in C there is no need to cast a `void*` pointer to any other data pointer. `void*` is the catch all type for pointers that is assignment compatible with every other (data pointer). Just from such sort of cast comes your problem: for C a function that is unknown is supposed to return `int`, your cast then tells him "I know what I am doing". So casting here is really bad, it hides a potential problem. You should carefully guide your professor to adopt a better programming style.

Comment: Ya ahah I think i see what your talking about now. I just was going by my operating systems professors sample code/notes.

Answer (score 2):

**Valigrind and GDB are your friend**

Please provide the entire code so we can compile it and help you out. Staring at source isn't a magic approach to debuggin :)

Ensure you are compiling with the debugging options (-g etc) on your compiler.

Otherwise, checkout valgrind's memcheck. When you have your compiled program, run:

`valgrind ./myprogram`

And you may get output similar to the following:

```
==584== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==584==    at 0x400480: segfaultme (p.c:6)
==584==    by 0x40049B: main (p.c:13)
==584== 
==584== Invalid write of size 4
==584==    at 0x400480: segfaultme (p.c:6)
==584==    by 0x40049B: main (p.c:13)
==584==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==584== 
==584== 
==584== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==584==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==584==    at 0x400480: segfaultme (p.c:6)
==584==    by 0x40049B: main (p.c:13)
==584==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==584==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==584==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==584==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==584==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 10485760.
```

Crack out GDB with:

`gdb ./myprog` then enter <kbd>r</kbd><kbd>return</kbd>

And you will get some more information on exactly where the segfault occurs:

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/aiden/tmp/a.out 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400480 in segfaultme (p=0x0) at p.c:6
6       *p = 22;
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.11.2-1.x86_64
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000400480 in segfaultme (p=0x0) at p.c:6
#1  0x000000000040049c in main () at p.c:13
```

Entering <kbd>b</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>return</kbd> will give you a backtrace too. In the above example we can see that line 6 of `p.c` in `segfaultme()` where I dereference `p` is the problem, and it shows `segfaultme()` was called by `main()`.

Hope this helps! Remember to get as much exposure to tools that help you!

Comment: In general you are entirely right, only that the first and best friend that you have is your compiler. The OP is just lying to his best friend by casting away return values of system functions ;-)

Comment: Thanks this does help, i never knew about valgrind before yall mentioned it.